porque me salen errores despues de usar "npm install @schematics/angular --save-dev"
En resumen queria usar Angular schematic para crear un nuevo modulo en mi proyecto de angular, pero por alguna razon no me dejaba, la solucion que me dio fue usar el comando "npm install @schematics/angular --save-dev", el problema es que despues de usar ese comando y cargo el proyecto, empezaron a aparecer un monton de errores en el ts donde antes no habia nada, esto es meramente visual, ya que puedo hacer npm start y se ejecuta sin problema, pero es molesto que pase esto.
Esto causo dos tipos de errores, el primero que algunas cosas marcaba que era posiblemente null como en la primera imagen,
Y el segundo error fue que en varios imports marca: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
Aclaro que es algo que pasa con respaldos de hace mas de 1 mes del mismo proyecto, osea fue algo que se movio en vscode o no se bien donde, porque ni reinstalando vscode, node o angularcli regreso a la normalidad, y se que es algo solo visual, pero es un tanto molesto
Para el primer error encontre que la solucion fue meterme a "settings" y en la barra de busqueda poner "@ext:vscode.typescript-language-features" a esto solo le agregue "strict" y me salio la opcion de "Strict Null Checks" con la que se quito estas alertas/errores

Pero no e encontrado alguna configuracion para quitar las alertas/errores de los imports. Puedo trabajar asi, pero si es algo molesto.


Declarar algo "constante" y luego asignarle otro valor es claramente un error en cualquier lenguaje. Es una contradicción; o es constante o es variable.

¡Bienvenido! Esos errores que te está marcando el linter de Typescript no son errores inexistentes, ni mucho menos. El sobreescribir el valor de una variable declarada con const genera un TypeError en tiempo de ejecución:


const perro = 34

perro = 32
console.log('Llega a esta línea de código')



El segundo error que te marca es un aviso de que si la función this.form.get() te devolviese null (que es una posibilidad) entonces tendrías otro TypeError en tiempo de ejecución por tratar de acceder a una propiedad de un null:


null.miPropiedad
console.log('Llega a esta línea de código')



Los TypeErrors son errores que pueden detener la ejecución de tu proyecto si no están debidamente controlados, como por ejemplo con un try/catch:


try {
  const perro = 34
  perro = 32
}
catch (error) {
  console.log('Se produce un error:', error.stack)
}

console.log('Llega a esta línea de código')



Como ves, ambos son errores que deberían de ser tratados si deseas que tú código siga ejecutándose.
El primero se puede arreglar declarando las variable como let en vez de como const:


let perro = 34
perro = 32
console.log('Llega a esta línea de código')



El segundo podrías llamar a la propiedad valueChanges solamente si lo que te devuelve la función this.form.get() no es null:


const thisFormGet = null

if (thisFormGet !== null) {
  thisFormGet.valueChanges
}

console.log('Llega a esta línea de código')




Bueno, mas bien son warnings, y gracias, pero el problema no son solo esos errores si no que son bastantes en todos los archivos ts que tengo, desde algunos imports a otros como los que mostre, el problema, como menciono, es que esos warnings o errores no existian antes de npm install

No, son más bien errores: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError. Si quieres que Typescript sea menos riguroso con tus errores y que te permita cometer más, puedes cambiarle la rigurosidad: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#strictness

@OscarI y te fijaste de tratar de solucionarlos? al prender TS y ponerlo estricto, lo que estas tratando de evitar son errores en tiempo de ejecucion, ya que TS no pasa de largo y se compila todo a js plano... la idea de usar TS es evitar errores que no ves en JS... pero al ser warnings, en realidad, si lo sacas de modo estricto todo funciona.

El primer error que presenta la imagen es un error, el segundo si es un warning avisándote de que es posible que el código acabe presentando un error a no ser que lo controles. Typescript una de las cosas que aporta es un mayor control sobre posible errores en el manejo de valores null o undefined. Es posible que al instalar la dependencia que comentas, esta te haya tocado el fichero tsconfig.json para habilitarte el modo "strict", con quitarlo desaparecerían todos los warnings de los que te avisa Typescript aunque TS lo que realmente quiera sea que trabajes en modo estricto.

Digo que no son errores porque la aplicacjion compila y corre bien(solo detecta el de la const perro).
Tratar de solucionarlos no seria buena opcion por que es una aplicacion grande, y realmente solo es algo visual y que molesta para trabajar.
En un momento edito mostrando los archivos tsconfig que tengo, pero modifique algunos y nada, igualmente abri un respaldo que tenia antes del install que hize y muestra los mismos errorres, resintale vscode y tampoco, no se si sea algo de vscode o que haya sido.

En este momento encontre donde posiblemente este el problema, en settings @ext:vscode.typescript-language-features strict, ahi pude quitarle el strict al null, ya solo me faltaria quitarlo de los imports pero de momento no e encontrado nada de eso
